# Pagination not working for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Video Explanation https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4HLAyVud6iLNjlHMGF3RXA3Qkk

I am trying to make a pagination, so far it is showing page links properly like 1 2 3 4 > but the problem is when i navigate to page 2 or any other page it take me to 404 page. Here is my pagination function

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'sp_pagination' ) ) { 

    function sp_pagination( $query = '', $echo = true ) {


        $prev_arrow = is_rtl() ? 'fa fa-angle-right' : 'fa fa-angle-left';
        $next_arrow = is_rtl() ? 'fa fa-angle-left' : 'fa fa-angle-right';

        // Get global $query
        if ( ! $query ) {
            global $wp_query;
            $query = $wp_query;
        }

        // Set vars
        $total  = $query->max_num_pages;
        $big    = 999999999;

        // Display pagination
        if ( $total > 1 ) {

            // Get current page
            if ( $current_page = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
                $current_page = $current_page;
            } elseif ( $current_page = get_query_var( 'page' ) ) {
                $current_page = $current_page;
            } else {
                $current_page = 1;
            }

            // Get permalink structure
            if ( get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) ) {
                if ( is_page() ) {
                    $format = 'page/%#%/';
                } else {
                    $format = '/%#%/';
                }
            } else {
                $format = '&paged=%#%';
            }

            $args = apply_filters( 'sp_pagination_args', array(
                'base'      => str_replace( $big, '%#%', html_entity_decode( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                'format'    => $format,
                'current'   => max( 1, $current_page ),
                'total'     => $total,
                'mid_size'  => 3,
                'type'      => 'list',
                'prev_text' => '<span class="' . $prev_arrow . '"></span>',
                'next_text' => '<span class="' . $next_arrow . '"></span>',
            ) );

            // Output pagination
            if ( $echo ) {
                echo '<div class="sp-pagination">' . paginate_links( $args ) . '</div>';
            } else {
                return '<div class="sp-pagination">' . paginate_links( $args ) . '</div>';
            }

        }

    }

}
```

And here is my query

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

        $portfolio_grid_query = new WP_Query( 
            array( 
                'post_type'             => 'portfolio',
                'post_status'           => 'publish',
                'name'                  => $portfolio_grid_title_slug,
                'posts_per_page'        => $portfolio_grid_item_limit,
                'category_name'         => $portfolio_grid_cats,
                'order'                 => $portfolio_order,
                'orderby'               => $portfolio_orderby,
                'paged'                 => $paged
            ) 
        );
```

here all the while loop and post structure goes and after while loop ends i put the pagination function like so:

```
sp_pagination($portfolio_grid_query, true);
```

It is showing all the navigation structure properly but the issue is when i navigate it takes me to 404 page instead of page 2 to show other remaining posts. Keep in mind i have total of 9 posts and i set posts_per_page to 6, which is showing me 6 posts on current page and if i click on page 2 link it should take me to other page to show remaining 3 posts.

Comment: what does the link look like

Comment: what link are you referring to.?

Comment: @Rahatulislam Would you please refer my link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38939212/wordpress-paginate-links-how-to-use-it/38939382#38939382 ?

Comment: your code results in links that should take you to the next page, what does that link look like? Does it make sense or do you see an error there?

Comment: @RST those links are "1 2 >"  they are normal but not functioning properly.

Comment: @purvik7373 no sir thats not working for me i have tried that solution, its same as mine and i am getting same issue.

Comment: Look up what a common link looks like, then answer my question again. It is difficult to help if you can't give answers to simple questions.

Comment: @RST if you are talking about the link structure in address bar then this is the url 'http://localhost/wordpress/portfolio/page/2/'. this link is fine but its contents are 'Oops! That page can’t be found.It looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try one of the links below or a search?'

Comment: @RST wait i ill make a video on it.

Comment: @RST here the video https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4HLAyVud6iLNjlHMGF3RXA3Qkk

Comment: what is the value of your post_per_page setting in wp admin

Comment: @RST the value is dynamic. in visual composer you can put any number.

Comment: Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768900/wordpress-pagination-not-working/13856345#13856345